# ModelForm. Why my form is not filled with data from model?

Tags: django

Why my form is not filled with data from model?

This is my model.py

```
class People(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

This is my forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm 

class EditForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = People
        exclude=('user',)
```

views.py

```
def edit_data(request):
    user = request.user
    people = People.objects.get(user=user)
    form = EditForm(request.POST, instance = people)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            print 'Error'
    else:
        form = EditForm()

    return render_to_response('profile.html',{'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

profile.html

```
<form action="/profile/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're redefining `form` in your `else` clause (to a new instance of your `EditForm`, which doesn't have the `instance` variable set). Remove the `else` (and the line under it) and you should be good to go.

Comment: You removed the lines: `else: form = EditForm()`?

Comment: @user1745580 girasquid is correct. If you did it and still doesn't work as you say, update your question with what you did and we'll take it from there.

Comment: I add in last else: form = EditForm(instance = a) and now it work. Thanks